# How can I schedule a query in Google BigQuery to append new data to table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying the new query scheduling feature in Google BigQuery, but I can't seem to get it to append new records to my table correctly.

I set `Custom schedule` to `every 15 minutes` and the `Destination table write preference` to `Append to table`.

```sql
SELECT DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME(logtime, 'America/Los_Angeles'), MINUTE) log_minute,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) unique_products
FROM mytable
WHERE DATE(logtime, 'America/Los_Angeles') >= "2019-05-01"
GROUP BY log_minute
ORDER BY log_minute
```

I expected to see 1 row per `log_minute`, but I'm seeing duplicates: 1 row per `log_minute` for each scheduled run so that after an hour, there are 5 duplicates of each row (1 at the start + 1 for every 15 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected to see 1 row per log_minute, but I'm seeing duplicates: 1 row per log_minute for each scheduled run

Do you want to append new rows? Of course you'll see a new row every time the query runs - because you are appending rows.

If you want to `UPDATE` the existing ones instead and add new ones, schedule a `MERGE`.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip, Felipe! For anyone who's trying to do the same thing, I edited the query to the following:

```sql
MERGE nextvr.sched_test_15min H
USING 
(
    SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME(logtime, 'America/Los_Angeles'), MINUTE)) log_minute,
      COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) users,
      COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) products
    FROM mytable
    WHERE DATE(logtime, 'America/Los_Angeles') >= "2019-05-01"
    GROUP BY log_minute
) N
ON H.log_minute = N.log_minute
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET users = N.users, products = N.products
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (log_minute, users, products)
        VALUES (log_minute, users, products)
```

When creating the scheduled query, under `Destination for query results` section, leave the `Table name` field blank.